# Asp.net C# MVC Common logic to separate dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm newbie with asp.net so forgive me if my question is too simple or may has no sense at all.

I made an asp.net mvc app from scratch, and found that a controller with the corresponding view could be a shared resource between couple of similar apps of mine. So I'm thinking how to do this. My first thoughts was to move the common logic to a separate dll, but i'm not sure that this is the right way to do this. Would the Route annotation still work, if I just import my dll?

Any suggestion is welcomed!!

Comment: no, you'd still need a controller. You could make a Nuget package which you could install into each of your apps, which would install all the necessary bits - controller, view and associated model files.  This is assuming you want to clone the functionality. Or are you saying you want to literally share it - i.e. all the apps redirect to the same controller at the same URL when deployed online?

Comment: you can call the controller and its action methods from different view corresponding to different controllers. It depends on how you want to call. If its through a link then you can use @Html.ActionLink and then pass on the parameters as controllerName, ActionMethodName etc. Creating a different Controller for shared resources won't be a bad idea but you can reuse it without doing that too I suppose.

Comment: @ADyson What I would like to archive is to create a module (the content would be the controller, and the view related files), and import this module into some projects. It would be even better if there would be some possibility to configure couple of properties also like the Route string, and to pass some function which the controller need to call to populate the view. So you are saying that the only thing I can share is going to be the view (the cshtml page, and the linked resources like css and js libs)?

Comment: No I didn't say that. I said you'd still need a controller file in the correct place in the app, which you can't achieve just by a DLL, because its status as a controller is dependent on its location in the folder structure, due to MVC's conventions. What you _can_ do, is bundle up View file, Controller file and anything else you need (JS, CSS) in a Nuget package which can easily install all of those files into the correct places within any given MVC project. You mention route strings - I believe this info can be included as an attribute of the controller action methods.